# Finding if value is a temporary

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a function that checks if the argument is a temporary value and returns a boolean.

Lets call it isTemp. Examples:

```
int a;
isTemp(a); // this should be false;

isTemp(43); // should be true;
```

I've started on the function using template arguments, however this didn't work and now I'm not sure on what to do:

```
template <typename T>
bool isTemp(T) { return false; }

template <typename T>
bool isTemp(const T) { return true; }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: For  C++03 you can still try with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to use *universal references* (introduced in C++11)

In C++ temporary values are usually represented by *rvalues* (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression), while everything else is treated as *lvalues* (can be put on both sides of assignment operators).

Universal references can represent both, and depending on what value passed they will coerced to *lvalue reference* or *rvalue reference*, which can be determined by `std::is_rvalue_reference`.

Here is an example code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool isTemp(T&& t) {
    return std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value;
}

int f() { return 0; }

int main() {
    int a;
    std::cout << isTemp(a) << std::endl;    // prints 0
    std::cout << isTemp(f()) << std::endl;  // prints 1
    std::cout << isTemp(43) << std::endl;   // prints 1
}
```

Comment: This checks if the argument was an rvalue, which is different to checking for a temporary object. For example, `f()` is an rvalue but its return value is not a temporary object. (Temporary objects must have class type, see [class.temporary]). Another example would be `isTemp( std::move(x) )`, this will give `1` despite there being no temporaries.

Comment: Many rvalues can appear on the left side of the assignment operator (even in C++98) . Your comment regarding assignment operator is more a historical curiousity rather than a definition of the terms.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks for the note, i've changed definition of _rvalues_ with one from standard. Speaking about, `std::move` example, it seems that they counted as _xvalues_ (eXpiring objects), that look much like temporary ("usually near the end of its lifetime") and represented by _ravlues_.