# Understanding return type of std::ranges::sort with temporary and prvalue arguments

Tags: c++, sorting, c++20, std-ranges, prvalue

I have issues understanding when does a type deduce to `std::ranges::dangling` when using named local variables vs a prvalue as arguments to `std::ranges::sort` algorithm  . For example I have function that returns a `prvalue`  to a standard container, say std::vector which I use directly as an argument to `std::ranges::sort`, then I expect to get a compilation error regarding `std::ranges::dangling` when I attempt to dereference the iterator, which is what I get :

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

auto get_data(){
    return std::vector<int>{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4};
}

auto get_sorted(){
    return std::ranges::sort(get_data());
}


int main(){
    auto it = get_sorted();
    *(it-1); //Compiler Error because it is a std::ranges::dangling iterator
}
```

However if I change the `get_sorted` function above slightly to first capture the vector in a named variable and use that instead to return the result of `std::ranges::sort`, then I don't get a dangling iterator, in the `main` even though the allocated vector in named variable should have been destroyed after the function `get_sorted` returned :

```
auto get_sorted(){
    auto vec = get_data();
    return std::ranges::sort(vec);
}


int main(){
    auto it = get_sorted();
    *(it-1); //Okay result  = 99
}
```

Even if I change `get_sorted` to use a named variable based container declared locally, I get a behavior where the compiler doesn't complain about dangling iterator on being dereferenced in its caller (say `main` function) .

```
//doesn't return a std::ranges::dangling
auto get_sorted(){
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4};
    return std::ranges::sort(vec);
}
```

and when I pass a prvalue vector to the `std::ranges::sort` algorithm, I again get a `std::ranges::dangling` as expected

```
//returns a std::ranges::dangling
auto get_sorted(){
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4};
    return std::ranges::sort(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4});
}
```

For the cases where I don't get an error by compiler regarding `std::ragnes::dangling` I do observe a runtime error when I compile with `fSanitize=address` option which is likely because the vectors that were allocated in named variable within the `get_sorted` function went out of scope as soon as the latter function returned.

However I would like to understand why using named variable within a function changes the return type of `get_sorted` function and possible a guide on how to use temporaries and prvalues containers correctly to get `std::ranges::dangling` whenever possible.

Comment: It's because your vector becomes unavailable / goes out of bounds. If you mark your vector static and you return a reference to the vector, your code will probably compile. You do exactly as the example shows: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/dangling , `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::ranges::dangling, decltype(dangling_iter)>);` will trigger. But I'm not 100% sure so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: All of your vectors get destroyed after the `sort` (+`return`) calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think I'm pretty sure it's because the code is creating temporaries that go out-of-bounds. The example code on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/dangling perfectly shows what you are doing, produces this behaviour.

The code (`return std::ranges::sort(get_data());`) is triggering the same static assert as in the example: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::ranges::dangling, decltype(dangling_iter)>);`.

This will yield a dangling type when the source goes out of bounds / will become inaccessible after the sort operation.

What you did in:

```
//doesn't return a std::ranges::dangling
auto get_sorted(){
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4};
    return std::ranges::sort(vec);
}
```

is trick this safety net into unsafe operations - The code using the *returned iterator* is trying to access freed memory (that's a big no-no). **There's no good way to detect this in the standard library, and so std::ranges library is not going to protect you from it.** In case of the dangling return type, [it's possible to detect a temporary argument with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367956/finding-if-value-is-a-temporary). So `std::ranges::sort` doesn't even do any sorting probably, if implemented efficiently, it just short-circuits to returning the dangling type.

A local variable will become unavailable after it's current scope, and this means that any references become dangling. The std::ranges library is doing it's best to try to protect you from doing this for simple cases (like your first one).

To make the code work you'll have to keep the vector available during any iterator operations:

```
auto get_data(){
    return std::vector<int>{1, 2, 99, 5, 9, 4};
}

auto get_sorted(std::vector<int>& data){
    return std::ranges::sort(data);
}


int main(){
    auto data = get_data(); // keep the vector in the same scope as the iterator operations
    auto it = get_sorted(data);
    *(it-1);
}
```

You can also do iterator operations in subscopes as long as you keep the vector alive in the parent scope(s).

To illustrate it live:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8b2945cfda85a20

As you can see, the vector gets destroyed before get_sorted even finishes.

Remember that *containers* contain data, and *algorithms* only provide a *view* (with iterators) into that data, or they modify existing data, they don't make copies (unless explicitly specified like with std::copy).

Comment: I  don't use `static` keyword to allocate the `std::vector` in named variable so I don't understand how I have reproduced the example like in the link you posted. It's quite obvious that static variables go out of scope when the program ends, but in my case the variable is not static. 

I understand also how to make the program safe. I am just looking for an explanation on why there are differences in compilation and program behaviour when I use temporary named variable vs prvalue

Comment: The named variable doesn't return dangling because after the `sort` call directly, there's nothing dangling. The data is still accessible after the sort call. It becomes inaccessible after the `return`. The `sort(std::vector<int>{})` temporary argument gets immediately destroyed after the `sort` call finishes, meaning it would return dangling data. The compiler / ranging library doesn't protect you from returning an iterator that will become danging (no way for the library to support that in all cases).

Comment: this is something I also guessed but I thought there might be a better explanation. But seems like there's an oversight from standard committee and compiler implementers to not look into this or miss this out... it doesn't help to make C++ any safer than before if there are such loopholes in the language

Comment: When using iterators, iterators are a _view_ of the data, not a _copy_. Iterating / sorting doesn't make a copy, and never will (in the standard). It's for efficiency and performance reasons. In C# you can do this, because it has automatic memory management, and every "complex" object (like vector) is passed as a reference. In C++ arguments can be passed as values, and values have a very strict lifetime. If you want to do this in C++, use smart pointers (but this will be a lot more work to implement).

Answer (score 3):

To solve the issue of dangling iterators, C++ ranges introduce the concept of [`borrowed_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/borrowed_range) to indicate that the iterator of such range is still valid when the range is destroyed.

Its definition is as follows:

```
template<class R>
  concept borrowed_range =
    ranges::range<R> &&
    (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<R> ||
    ranges::enable_borrowed_range<std::remove_cvref_t<R>>);
```

lvalue ranges are *always* borrowed ranges because the reference itself does not own the data so if it dies it does not affect the original range.

For rvalue ranges, it is difficult for the compiler to infer whether its iterator can be *borrowed*, so it needs to specialize `enable_borrowed_range` to imply that the range is a borrowed range, such as `subrange`, etc.

In your example, the return type of `ranges::sort` is `borrowed_iterator_t<R>`, which will be aliased as `dangling` when `R` does not satisfy `borrowed_range` (See [why the standard is designed to return `dangling` in such case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945216/why-do-std-range-algorithms-return-stdrangesdangling-for-rvalue-arguments-in)).

According to the definition of `borrowed_range`, the *named* vector is an lvalue, so it is a borrowed range, and the rvalue vector is not a borrowed range so `ranges::sort` always returns `dangling`,
which is the result of your observation.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ranges::dangling` is returned purely based on type and value category analysis. It cannot magically detect other use-after-end-of-lifetime issues and is not a replacement for UB sanitizers.

You seem to expect that

```
auto get_sorted(){
    auto vec = get_data();
    return std::ranges::sort(vec);
}
```

to return `std::ranges::dangling`. However it becomes clear that this is impossible if you save the result first. I think you should agree that the following should not result in `std::ranges::dangling`:

```
void sort(){
    auto vec = get_data();
    auto it = std::ranges::sort(vec); //it should not be std::dangling
    *it; //This line should compile
}
```

If you agree with the above, it makes no sense if adding a return magically changes the type to `std::ranges::dangling`.

```
auto get_sorted_2(){
    auto vec = get_data();
    auto it = std::ranges::sort(vec); //it should not be std::dangling
    *it;
    return it;  
}
```

The way C++ works is that the expression `std::ranges::sort(vec)` has a fixed type once the type of vec is fixed. It is impossible for the expression to suddenly change to a different type just because of an extra `return`. The `auto` in your `get_sorted` has to deduce to the same type as what `auto it` would deduce the type for `it`, and it cannot be `std::ranges::dangling`.

What `std::ranges::dangling` tells you is that the constrained algorithm cannot return anything meaningful without the danger of dangling, based solely on the analysis of your call to the algorithm, regardless of any later use.

The document is clear. It is returned for certain constrained algorithms when applied to rvalue ranges that do not model `borrowed_range`. That's the only case it detects, it does not and cannot detect later usage that would lead to use out of lifetime.

In your code sample, `std::ranges::sort` is a constrained algorithm called on a rvalue `std::vector`, which does not model `borrowed_range`, which basically means it is not possible to obtain an iterator to a rvalue `std::vector` without the caveat of dangling, that's why it returns `std::ranges::dangling`. If `std::vector` had been incorrectly declared to model `borrowed_range`, the compiler will happily return an iterator instead of `std::ranges::dangling`. In other words, the compiler determines the return type should be `std::ranges::dangling` solely on how `std::vector` advertises itself to behave. It does not really examine the code to see whether something dangles to make this decision.

It is now natural to see why it is designed such that `std::ranges::dangling` will never be returned for a lvalue range because the returned iterator is at least safe enough to use in the same scope as the range.

**Key point**: Whether the return type is `std::ranges::dangling` is the result of a type-level calculation and has nothing to do with actual dangling analysis performed by the compiler (e.g. for emitting warnings).

Comment: I agree with all of the above, but I some how cannot accept that such behavior is not flagged by the standard or the compiler. This just expands the language with more loopholes. Appreciate  your explanation though.